# Export with additional options Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock 1.2.5.

These are the options I have with my chart.

I am adding colors to yAxis using `axis.addPlotBand` based on certain conditions.

Also, I am using `axis.addPlotLine` to draw line some plot values.

Both, these options are set after chart is drawn. As, I have dynamic values.

This works fine no problem. Lately, I have enabled `Export` options.

Now, The exported `pdf` is not showing above mentioned changes. How do I do that ?

Second, I have enabled Legend. Is it possible to not to include Legend while exporting chart.

Comment: Regarding plotLines/Bands - this is known issue: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1114 To add/remove options when exporting use exporting.chartOptions.

Comment: @PawełFus: And Is there any way to exclude legend in Export / Print ?

Comment: For printing is not possible, but for exporting should be done using chartOptions as I said before. I have checked bug-tracker, and looks like since v3.0 we have bug with this: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1759